# Error in my c program

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to compile program for pic18f4550 using C18 Compiler. I have a syntax error at this line:

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) _USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 5):

`__attribute__ ((packed))` is a GNU extension and is not C and this syntax is not available in C18.

Note that regarding structure padding, C18 compiler [documentation](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51288f.pdf) says:

> **ANSI C Standard**: “The padding and alignment of members of structures (6.5.2.1).”
>
> **Implementation**: Members of structures and unions are aligned on byte boundaries.

so there is no need to pack the structure members through compiler extension.